# How to compare and group paired values across groups pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if something similar has been asked before, I searched around but couldn't figure out a solution.

My data looks like this, except with many more subjects (Math, Science, History, etc):

```
data = {'Group':['Winner','Winner','Loser','Loser'],
        'MathStudy': ['Read','Read','Notes','None'],'ScienceStudy': ['Tutor','Read','None','Notes'],
        'MathScore':[90,100,40,50],'ScienceScore':[100,100,40,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

[image]

Each row is a student, and I'd like to see which method of studying ( Tutor/Read/Notes/None) results in the best average score, based on group.

I would like to have an average over all subjects. Example: Reading results in an average score of 95 across all subjects in the Winner group, compared to 60 in the Loser group.

Any help or pointers are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have an average over all subjects

```
df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda f: numpy.mean(f[['MathScore', 'ScienceScore']].values))
```

group by & apply the `numpy.mean` function for each group.

> I'd like to see which method of studying ( Tutor/Read/Notes/None) results in the best average score, based on group.

The analysis would get a lot simpler if the data is reshaped first:

```
dfv = pd.concat([df[['Group', 'MathStudy', 'MathScore']].rename(columns=rename),
                 df[['Group', 'ScienceStudy', 'ScienceScore']].rename(columns=rename)])
# dfv outputs:

    Group  Study  Score
0  Winner   Read     90
1  Winner   Read    100
2   Loser  Notes     40
3   Loser   None     50
0  Winner  Tutor    100
1  Winner   Read    100
2   Loser   None     40
3   Loser  Notes     50
```

Then calculate the mean. Here are a couple of ways to do that:

```
dfv.groupby(['Group', 'Study']).Score.mean()
# output:

Group   Study
Loser   None      45.000000
        Notes     45.000000
Winner  Read      96.666667
        Tutor    100.000000
Name: Score, dtype: float64

dfv.pivot_table(index='Group', columns='Study', values='Score', aggfunc='mean')

# output:

Study   None  Notes       Read  Tutor
Group
Loser   45.0   45.0        NaN    NaN
Winner   NaN    NaN  96.666667  100.0
```